# Need Help in Multiplayer Game Libgdx Android

Tags: android, facebook, libgdx, multiplayer, appwarp

I'm currently developing a card game for Android. I've completed single player game. I'm having trouble in multiplayer side. For multiplayer, I'm using Appwrap. I'm new to libgdx and appwrap. Multiplayer gameplay can be done with appwrap. What i want is to create a group of the users where they can chat with each other and play the game. user can create account by signing in with their facebook account. with this they can find their friends and group his/her friend is associated with. i should have different server to store user and group information and for gameplay appwrap should be used. Is there any opensource project that has implemented facebook friends and groups to chat with the group member? (currently i'm getting help from superjumper opensource game for multiplayer gameplay)I'm confused right now. I don't know how i can achieve facebook signin and groups.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you need to customise the AppWarp server side code. AppWarp provides [AppWarpS2](http://appwarps2.shephertz.com/) where you can customise the server as per your need.For storing data on the server, you can use [App42 Cloud APIs](http://api.shephertz.com/app42-dev.php) which you can call from your customised server as well as from your client.
Also, if you face any problem you can always write on AppWarp community [forum](http://forum.shephertz.com/?qa=questions).